Use of Query vs Relationship reference in SwiftData for presenting child objects in views
Imagine your domain involves some kind of infinite tree structure, like a folder structure. Using SwiftData.
Should you use @Query in each node to get the child nodes, or should you just use the @Relationship reference? What are the pros and cons?
Common code:
@Model
class Node {
    let id = UUID()
    var parent: Node?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var children: [Node]
    var name: String { "node: \(id)".prefix(5).description }

    init(children: [Node]) {
        self.children = children
    }
}

Example with @Query
struct NodeViewUsingQuery: View {
    @Environment(NavigationPathWrapper.self) var navigation
    let node: Node

    // Use a query to get child nodes
    @Query var childNodes: [Node]
    init(node: Node) {
        self.node = node
        self._childNodes = Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.parent?.id == node.id })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Nodes:")
            ForEach(childNodes, id: \.id) { child in
                Text(child.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        navigation.path.append(child)
                    }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(node.name)
    }
}

Example with @Relationship reference
struct NodeViewUsingRelationship: View {
    @Environment(NavigationPathWrapper.self) var navigation
    let node: Node

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Nodes:")
            ForEach(node.children, id: \.id) { child in
                Text(child.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        navigation.path.append(child)
                    }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(node.name)
    }
}

PS: My real domain is close to a folder structure with folders and files. Where I support adding, deleting, editing, and moving nodes.

The second option is always faster, sometimes more sometimes less.
